# C# web form automation; clicking a radio button

Tags: c#, automation, radio-button

I'm writing a C# program to automate filling out a web form. Eveything is going good except for the fact that I need to click a certain radio button on the web page.

There are two radio buttons in the group; lets say the id is "months". the first radio button is checked by default, but I need the second one checked. How do I acomplish this? I can see that they each have a different value associated with them, but I'm sure if or how to exploit this to acomplish what I need.

Comment: Web form controls are ultimately just name-value pairs in HTTP POST request. So the usual approach to form automation is to fill it out in a browser while sniffing requests/responses with a debugging proxy. Then you'll know what data you need to send to the server to get the response you want.

Comment: I need to fill this out as though a human was doing it.